# Translate a Linq query into a database View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2008, view

I have a table `TestPack` in my database and this table has `1-N` relationship with table `Documentation` and `InternalWalk`. Below code compiles Test Pack status report by fetching all Test Packs from database and iterating over each of them the report gets compiled. My application is architectured in a way that Database is hosted on a `Windows` Server machine (SQL Server) and client applications run over the network. So the below code first gets list of all TestPacks and in each loop iteration it again queries the `Documentation` and `InternalWalk` tables. This slows down things a lot.

```
var AllTestPacks = Project.GetAllTestPacksFromDB();
foreach (var tp in AllTestPacks)
{
    var testPack = new TestPackStatus { TestPackNo = tp.test_pack_no };
    var documentation = tp.Documentations.LastOrDefault();
    if (documentation != null && documentation.status == "Accepted" && documentation.acceptance_date >= cutOffDate)
        testPack.Documentation = documentation.ReadinessDate;
    var internalWalk = tp.InternalWalks.LastOrDefault();
    if (internalWalk != null && internalWalk.status == "Accepted" && internalWalk.acceptance_date >= cutOffDate)
        testPack.InterWalks = internalWalk.AcceptanceDate;
   StatusData.Add(testPack);
}
```

I was thinking if  I can translate the below code into a database `View` and I simply fetch the data from the `View`, that would speed things up significantly. How can I can translate the above code into a `View`.

Here is what I have tried so far but I am unable to implement this `LastOrDefault()` thing.

```
SELECT dbo.TestPack.test_pack_no, dbo.Documentation.rfi_no, dbo.Documentation.rfi_date, dbo.Documentation.status, 
FROM dbo.TestPack INNER JOIN dbo.Documentation ON dbo.TestPack.id = dbo.Documentation.test_pack_id WHERE (dbo.Documentation.status = 'Accepted')
```

Comment: What does `GetAllTestPacksFromDB` actually do?  Does it load all of the related entities for `Documentation` and `InternalWalk` for a `TestPack` without providing a predicate (where clause)?  In other words, it maybe loading back a lot of data, therefore the slowdown could be in the `GetAllTestPacksFromDB` call rather than the Linq queries on the loaded entity graph.

Comment: Are you attempting to assign a datetime value to a collection? `testPack.Documentation = documentation.ReadinessDate`

Comment: @user978139 `GetAllTestPacksFromDB` is not slowing down things that much.. the problem is looping and then inside each iteration accessing `Documentation` and `InternalWalk` tables. `TestPackStatus` is a separate class in which `testPack.Documentation` is a `DateTime` property

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to join onto the "latest" `Documentation` or `InternalWalk` record by `test_pack_no` and sorting by `acceptance_date` to distinguish the latest record, the following SQL (excluding the table variables and replaced with your own tables) could be placed into a stored procedure passing `@cutoff` as a parameter:

```
declare @TestPack table (test_pack_no int)
insert into @TestPack values (1)
insert into @TestPack values (2)

declare @Documentation table (test_pack_no int, Name varchar(20), status varchar(20), acceptance_date datetime)
insert into @Documentation values (1, 'Doc 1', 'Accepted', '21 Dec 2015')
insert into @Documentation values (1, 'Doc 2', 'Accepted', '22 Dec 2015')
insert into @Documentation values (2, 'Doc 1', 'Non-Accepted', '22 Dec 2015')
insert into @Documentation values (2, 'Doc 2', 'Accepted', '21 Dec 2015')

declare @InternalWalk table (test_pack_no int, Name varchar(20), status varchar(20), acceptance_date datetime)
insert into @InternalWalk values (1, 'Walk 1', 'Accepted', '20 Dec 2015')
insert into @InternalWalk values (1, 'Walk 2', 'Accepted', '21 Dec 2015')

declare @cutoff datetime = '21 dec 2015'

;with cte_Documentation
as
(
    select
        row_number() over (partition by test_pack_no order by acceptance_date desc) [RN], *
    from
        @Documentation
    where
        status='Accepted'
        and acceptance_date >= @cutoff
),
cte_InternalWalk
as
(
    select
        row_number() over (partition by test_pack_no order by acceptance_date desc) [RN], *
    from
        @InternalWalk
    where
        status='Accepted'
        and acceptance_date >= @cutoff
),
    cte_TestPack
    as
    (
        select
            tp.*, d.status, d.Name [Doc_Name],     d.acceptance_date     [Doc_AcceptDate], iw.Name [InternalWalk_Name], iw.acceptance_date     [InternalkWalk_AcceptDate]
        from
            @TestPack tp
            left join cte_Documentation d on d.test_pack_no=tp.test_pack_no     and d.RN=1
        left join cte_InternalWalk iw on     iw.test_pack_no=tp.test_pack_no and iw.RN=1
)
select * from cte_TestPack
```

It was unclear from your example exactly what columns were filtered and needed as part of your result.

You simply have EF call the SPROC passing the cut-off date as a parameter which will return a flat-structure which can then be converted into your individual objects `TestPack`, `Documentation` and `InternalWalk`